# HTML and Touch Devices

Tags: ipad, click, touch, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive web site and one of the requirements is to have elements that are only 'clickable' on mobile devices, especially iPhones and iPads (not on PC browsers).

Say for example, displaying phone numbers which can only be clicked on an touch device ... but on desktop browsers it should only display and not be clickable.

Is it possible to this?

If so, can anyone guide me on how to go about doing this please.

Thank you.

Comment: @Gus: i tried this: 'function isTouchDevice() {
    return "ontouchstart" in window;'
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP user agent detection,for example like this:

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad") || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone")){
    echo '<a href='foo'>bar</a>'
}
else{
    echo 'bar'
}
?>
```

Or in JavaScript (replace bar with the link location and foo with a fitting id.):

```
function iPhoneLinks(){
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        document.getElementById('foo').href='bar';
    }
}
<body onload='iPhoneLinks();'>
    <a id='foo'>This will only be a link on iOS</a>
```

Untested but should work

Comment: thanks but I want to do it without php because its a editor content ... I'am developing the site in wordpress